# Gas solubility in water

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, solubility

Good morning,
I know that Henry's law describes the gas solubility in water with partial pressure of a specific gas.
For example the oxygen concentration in water, under atmospheric pressure, is

$\mathrm{C = P_{O_2} * k}$, where $\mathrm{P_{O_2}}$ is $\mathrm{0.21}$ bar.

But if I have a steam-water mixure, how I can calculate the solubility (for example in a deaerator)?
What data I need to calculate that solubility?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you feel that you can't use Henry's law for this?

Comment: Well if you are constantly deaerating, then then you are not at equilibrium with air (oxygen = 0.21 bar).  The equilibrium would be with the small amount of oxygen in the deaerator, but presumably your goal is to approach "zero" oxygen.

Comment: If that's the case, I don't think we have enough data to solve for such a dynamical system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the oxygen content (partial pressure) of the steam-water mixture with which you are purging the system.

The water being purged will come to equilibrium with the purge gas based on Henry's law, just as in your example of atmospheric conditions, except that the partial pressure of oxygen in the steam should be much lower.